# Generate a list with lambdas in kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and lambdas and I'm trying to understand it. I'm trying to generate a list of 100 random numbers. 
This works:

```
private val maxRandomValues = (1..100).toList()
```

But I want to do something like that:

```
private val maxRandomValues = (1..100).forEach { RandomGenerator().nextDouble() }.toList()
```

But this is not working. I'm trying to figure out how to use the values generated into `forEach` are used in the `toList()`

Comment: The problem with your sample is that `forEach` does not return a value. In @Sergey Rybalkin's answer, they use `map`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's way better to use `kotlin.collections` function to do this:

```
List(100) {
    Random.nextInt()
}
```

According to `Collections.kt`

```
inline fun <T> List(size: Int, init: (index: Int) -> T): List<T> = MutableList(size, init)
```

It's also possible to generate using range like in your case:

```
(1..100).map { Random.nextInt() }
```

The reason you can't use `forEach` is that it return `Unit` (which is sort of like `void` in Java, C#, etc.).  `map` operates  `Iterable` (in this case the `range` of numbers from 1 to 100) to **map** them to a different value. It then returns a list with all those values.  In this case, it makes more sense to use the `List` constructor above because you're not really "mapping" the values, but creating a list

Comment: I used that List(100){Random.nextInt()} statement. What I don't understand is what is the origin of that kind of structure (Collection constructor and a body). I'm jumping from the verbosity of java and I'm completely lost.

Comment: @Killrazor lets check step by step: 1. List(10,(index: Int) -> { index*index })

Comment: @Killrazor kotlin allows to omit 2. List(10, { index*index })

Comment: @Killrazor it's possible to move last parameter out of () braces if it is lambda 3: List(10) { index*index }

Answer (score 2):

Beside using constructor: `List(10, { Random.nextInt() })`,
Kotlin also has a built-in function for this purpose: `buildList { repeat(10) { add(Random.nextInt()) } }`

See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html